# Get the content of a child node from the parent selected by the listbox

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

i would ask you if it's possible to do the following task:

this is my xml file:

```
<SETTING_LIST>
    <setting>
      <name>first</name>
      <enable>the command...</enable>
      <disable>the command...</disable>
      <check>the command...</check>
      <word>first</word>
      <ifchecktrue>true</ifchecktrue>
      <usegrep>true</usegrep>
    </setting>
   <setting>
      <name>second</name>
      <enable>the command...</enable>
      <disable>the command...</disable>
      <check>the command...</check>
      <word>first</word>
      <ifchecktrue>true</ifchecktrue>
      <usegrep>true</usegrep>
    </setting>
  </SETTING_LIST>
```

so the user will select from a listbox the name of the parent node like "first" or "second", than i'd need something that give me back the content as string of the child node . I tried something like this but it doesen't work.

```
private void checkbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selectednode = Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            string prompt;

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("dati.txt");

            XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("setting/" + selectednode + "/check");
            prompt = node.InnerText;

            MessageBox.Show(prompt);
        }
```

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq ;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public static void Main()
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            string name = "first";

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("setting")
                .Where(x => (string)x.Element("name") == name).FirstOrDefault()
                .Elements().GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => (string)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }

}
```